# Change R assignment operators to red complete arrows in VS Code?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, assignment-operator

I am new to VS Code and trying to use R in VS Code.
I was wondering how to change R assignment operators to the red ones(arrows) as showed in the VS Code website.

Here is the website:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/r#_code-completion-IntelliSense

Here is the image I'm looking at:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a font with ***ligatures***. One of the most common to use is `FiraCode`. To install it, check [here](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/Installing).

Then, in VSCode, go to `settings.json` and paste the following lines (check the full instructions [here](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/VS-Code-Instructions).

```json
"editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",
"editor.fontLigatures": true
```

After that, close/reopen VSCode, and it should work.

[image]